# c# IEnumerable<object> is bound to XDocument changes

Tags: c#, xml, list, linq, ienumerable

I have an XML file as following:

```
<products>
  <product id="1" name="USB Flash Memory 2 GB" />
  <product id="2" name="USB Flash Memory 8 GB" />
  <product id="3" name="Wireless Multi Media Keyboard" />
</products>
```

I used `XDocument` to read the file and stored the query result in a variable of type `IEnumerable<Product>`.

If I added a new element to the `XDocument` the variable is updated automatically, so I thought that there is some bug so I tried that with `List<Product>` type variable and it worked (i.e. adding an element to the `XDocument` don't auto update with that input)

So my question is why the `IEnumerable` is bound to the `XDocument` changes while the `List` is not ?

**Full Code:**

```
namespace IEnumerableTest
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace IEnumerableTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static string path = @"Products.xml";
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
        IEnumerable<Product> productsEnum;
        List<Product> productsList;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            productsEnum =
                from p in xDoc.Descendants("product")
                select new Product
                {
                    ID = int.Parse(p.Attribute("id").Value),
                    ProductName = p.Attribute("name").Value
                };

            productsList =
                (from p in xDoc.Descendants("product")
                 select new Product
                 {
                     ID = int.Parse(p.Attribute("id").Value),
                     ProductName = p.Attribute("name").Value
                 }).ToList();
        }
        
        void BindDataGridView()
        {
            dataGridViewEnum.DataSource = productsEnum.ToList();
            dataGridViewList.DataSource = productsList;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindDataGridView();
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XElement newProduct =
                new XElement("product",
                new XAttribute("id", 4),
                new XAttribute("name", "Wireless USB Optical Mouse"));

            xDoc.Root.Add(newProduct);

            BindDataGridView();
        }
    }
}
```

The result is like this:

[image]

Comment: And `IEnumerable` is like a promise of data, so it's only when you loop over it, that is when the Linq query you have here is actually executed.

Comment: `ToList` creates a copy. `IEnumarable` uses the original references.

Comment: @imsmn No, that is a bad description.

Comment: @DavidG Feel free to improve it, always happy to describe things a bit better in the future.

Comment: @imsmn I already did in my comment. ToList is forcing the query to be executed immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `IEnumerable` is like a promise of data, so it's only when you loop over it (or use something like a `ToList` on it), that is when the Linq query you have here is actually executed. Consider the following code:

```
void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => DoubleNumber(x));

    Console.WriteLine($"There are {numbers.Count()} numbers that were doubled");
    Console.WriteLine($"There are {numbers.Count()} numbers that were doubled");
}

public int DoubleNumber(int value)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Doubling the number {value}");
    return value * 2;
}
```

The output from this is actually:

```
Doubling the number 1
Doubling the number 2
Doubling the number 3
Doubling the number 4
Doubling the number 5
There are 5 numbers that were doubled
Doubling the number 1
Doubling the number 2
Doubling the number 3
Doubling the number 4
Doubling the number 5
There are 5 numbers that were doubled
```

Note how the entire collection of numbers was calculated **twice**. If you add `.ToList()` to the end of the first line though, that will create all the numbers in memory only once and give you this output:

```
Doubling the number 1
Doubling the number 2
Doubling the number 3
Doubling the number 4
Doubling the number 5
There are 5 numbers that were doubled
There are 5 numbers that were doubled
```

Comment: Okay, I got it. When I changed the `XDocument` and called the `productsEnum` it was updated because the query run again but this time with the `XDocument` updated with new element.